# Divide items into batch of numbers for csv

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items e.g

> id 
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   10
>   11
>   12
>   13

I want to write this to csv and do it in batches of 5 so when it reaches id 5 it will go to next batch. I was thinking of doing mod to cater for this so

```
int noOfIds = MyIDList.Count % 5; // to get the number of loops i need

List<MyIDList> topFiveID = (from c in MyIDList
                select c).Take(5).ToList(); // get top 5 from the list
```

Then I am getting the rest by

```
List<MyIDList> restOfIDs = MyIDList.Where(c => !topFiveID.Any(tc => tc.ID == c.ID)).ToList();
```

Now I can see this can cater for up to 9 ids, can someone please tell me how to cater for all the ids no matter how many are there.

Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: i personally would just put it together in a loop

Comment: Would SkipWhile or TakeWhile be useful in this situation? I'm not clear on what you're asking.

Comment: Are you attempting to write to different csv files in each batch, or a new line for each batch?

Comment: @DaveZych same csv different line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will return batches of a given size from an enumeration:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    int batchSize)
{
    var batch = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        batch.Add(item);
        if (batch.Count == batchSize)
        {
             yield return batch;
             batch = new List<TSource>();
        }
    }

    if (batch.Any()) yield return batch;
}
```

Used like:

```
foreach (var list in MyIdList.Batch(5))
{
    // list is an IEnumerable<T> containing up to 5 items
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", String.Join(",", list));
}
```

Comment: Why mark the yielded list as read only?  It's not re-used internally, so even if they try to be clever and cast it to `List` and mutate it, they can only shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: @Servy: I've found that if library users can't mutate data to start, they're less likely to get in the habit of relying on implementation details.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I tried your answer but my list in foreach loop is always null even though i have 6 items. The MyIdList is an object containing many properties

Comment: The 'batch = new List<TSource>()' should be included with the yield in the if condition.  So you need braces around all that.

Comment: @sixlettervariables i tested it...it work but would i be able to exclude the 5 previous records from foreach loop. right now say if we have 6 records it writes first 5 batch to file then it writes the 5 + 1 again to second line...hope it is clear

Comment: @Sam1: then use Skip, `MyIdList.Skip(5).Batch(5)`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables isn't this going to skip my first batch?

Comment: @Sam1: You asked how to skip the previous 5 records. As it is written in my answer it will write 5 to a line each time until it gets to the end (and will write up to 5 from the last bit).

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following

```
MyGroupedIDs = MyIDList.Select((v, i) => new {GID = i/5; Value = v})
                       .GroupBy(p => p.GID);
```

This will group the ids by the index divided by 5, which will floor because they are ints.  So the first 5 items will have a 'GID' of 0, the next 5 will have 1, and so on.